# Am trying to create a date field where a user can select when to set an appointment with a worker. Am only getting a blank field with no Date picker

Tags: django

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Plumbing', 'Plumbing'),
        ('Electrical', 'Electrical'),
        ('Cleaning', 'Cleaning'),
    )
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    task_date = models.DateField(_("Task Date"), blank=True, null=True)
    task_location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    task_description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

forms.py file

```
class AppointmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user','worker','status']
        widgets = {'task_date': forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y')}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see yours imports, but try to import widgets from django.forms and  use "widgets.DateInput" instead of "forms.DateInput" in AppointmentForm like this:

```
from django.forms import widgets

    class AppointmentForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Appointment
            fields = '__all__'
            exclude = ['user','worker','status']
            widgets = {'task_date': widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
```

Comment: cool... i also had to add a class DateInput(forms.DateInput) and it worked